# Controling USB port's power using Assembly program

Tags: assembly, usb

I would like to write a program (Assembly), that allows me to control the power supply from a USB port to a motor. I've been told it's possible, but I would like to know how it can be done, I'm not asking for someone to write the code, I just want to know the method.

Comment: I would advised against directly driving a motor. It would not be too difficult to simply plug in a usb -> tty serial adapter or even an arduino that would talk with a proper hardware motor driver.

Comment: You can't turn off the +5V power supply of PC's USB port, not without turning off the PC. You'd have to do something like pcnate suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a much easier way of doing this would be to use something like the following devices and do it via hardware. These would provide a better programming interface with little hardware knowledge needed. You would also avoid trying to get some USB host controller that likely has to have custom code written to get the USB power method working and if you're very lucky, it won't fry the controller.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11113

http://www.robotshop.com/en/pololu-dual-dc-motor-driver-1a-4-5v-3-5v-tb6612fng.html

Comment: The [Pololu Simple Motor controllers](https://www.pololu.com/category/94/pololu-simple-motor-controllers) have a USB interface so that would be an easier method than integrating the two products you mentioned.  Keep in mind that you would proably need another power source to actually power the motors since the USB port cannot supply much current.  Also, we don't have example code in assembly.